# Cloth falling through rigid body

Tags: cloth-simulation

Followed every step of this very simple [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7h89tkUJLuM&list=PLkoR6rvf_v0KDA1Yxd3k2Rq5pfek6PmqJ&index=3) on cloth simulation and I can't seem to be able to make my top stay on the model.

[image: cloth before simulation]

[image: cloth simulation]

I've tried everything from adjusting the cloth simulation parameters to flipping normals but nothing seems to work.

My cloth parameters are as follows:
[image]

My model's parameters are as follows:
[image]

Everything else has default values. My file can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vK8hZv44klcoHdKj74VycEWoB96C3VRT/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: hello, maybe share your file so that people can try: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @mooboots just uploaded

Comment: hello @ user2724072, you need to put the link here

Answer (score 1):

i selected theses vertices and tapped: S -> X -> 1.3

[image]

ähm...yeah, my screenshots are not telling the truth -> of course you should only select the vertices from the front side (the screenshot shows also selected vertices on back side)

i did the same on the back:

[image]

ähm...same, my screenshots are not telling the truth -> of course you should only select the vertices from the back side (the screenshot shows also selected vertices on front side)

i turned up the quality steps to 8 (so that Blender won't use cached data) and i got this:

[image]

result:

[image]